# Boundary of non-overlapping regions of intersecting polygons

Tags: python, geometry

Given a list of polygons, I am trying to find the boundaries of all the distinct,non-overlapping regions.

```
polygon_lst = []
for xyloc in xylocs:
    polygon_lst.append(Polygon(xyloc))
```

It is a similar problem to [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187402/how-to-find-the-intersection-areas-of-overlapping-buffer-zones-in-single-shapefi). However, I get an error when I run the unary_union operation:

```
from shapely.geometry import LineString
layer = polygon_lst
rings = [LineString(list(pol.exterior.coords)) for pol in layer]
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize
```

> ERROR:shapely.geos:TopologyException: found non-noded intersection
>   between LINESTRING (103.333 327.917, 103 328) and LINESTRING (104.2
>   327.2, 103 328) at 103.00000000000006 328

I have tried an alternate approach where I create a mask of all the polygons overlaid on top of one another. Then I try to extract distinct regions by a Canny detector and findContour function in opencv. However, the boundaries yielded by this methods are connected (not one boundary per distinct region) and non-closed.

[image]
[image]

What would be a good way that I could go about finding these non-overlapping regions and their boundaries?

Answer (score 0):

Boolean operations on arbitrary polygons is a much harder problem than it first appears, largely because of the degeneracy problem.

If you render the polygons to a buffer, flood fill the margins, and then take contours, you will achieve your objective.

All the bits and pieces to do this are available in the binary image library
(You need drawbinary.c to draw the polys and do the flood fill, and binaryutils.c or chaincodes.c to get the contours depending how you want them (as a list of xys or as a chain of up down, right left commands)

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/binaryimagelibrary